# MariaDB server synchronization

Tags: mysql, synchronization

Thus far I have found two trigger driven MariaDB synchronization utilities - SymmetricDS and PervaSync.  Quite apart from the fact that they are rather pricey (which may be ok) what I do not like is that they both require a Java capable server (Tomcat) to be installed.  I run Nginx and have no real desire to have anything else there.  Are there any equivalents that are written in PHP? Or perhaps an open source/MIT licensed option.  My searches thus far have not revealed any alternatives. I'd be most grateful for any suggestions

---

What I would expect from the synchronization tool is listed below

- Is able to periodically (say every 5-10 minutes) synchronize a set of N MariaDB databases (4 for starters but more in due course) that are located in different geographic reigons
- The various DBs are subject to alterations (INSERTS, DELETES, UPDATES) as a result of user activity in their respective regions.  However, there is a cast iron guarantee that operations in one region will never cause conflicts with those performed in any other region
- The entire purpose behind the synchronization is to allow users to seamlessly access their data from another region if and when required
- Speed is not an issue - updates at a rate of once every few minutes will do nicely
- We run PHP on Nginx.  Running a secondary server is not an option - and certainly not Tomcat et al.
- The ideal solution would be one that runs as a native appliction (I am thinking a compiled package running on Ubuntu) or as a PHP script.
- At the moment we are operating with an in-house synchronization solution that squirrels away changes **before** they are committed to the database.  Those changes are periodically lifted by a "synchronizing server" which then handles with the task of getting all the other sibling servers into line.  This is working.  Nevertheless it is a home grown solution and outwith our area of expertise.  That is why I am looking around for possible options.

Comment: @Izzy - there you go.  A few more details for you.

Comment: Looks like [MySQL Cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Cluster) (or the MariaDB equivalent – "Galera Cluster" AFAIK) might be an option for you. You can e.g. [see here](https://xuri.me/2013/11/20/install-mysql-cluster-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts.html) for an Ubuntu install (or [here for Galera](https://blog.mariadb.org/installing-mariadb-galera-cluster-on-debian-ubuntu/)).

Comment: Thanks - the principal reason for not considering Galera is that given the fact that it attempts real-time updates - i.e. synchronous replication - there is a latency determined by the slowest node in the cluseter.

Comment: I see. But IMHO that depends on configuration: [How to Set Up Asynchronous Replication from Galera Cluster](http://www.severalnines.com/blog/asynchronous-replication-galera-cluster-mysql-server-gtid) indicates it can be set up asynchronous as well. (Btw: that was the first hit on a [Google search for "Galera asynchronous"](https://www.google.com/search?q=galera+asynchronous) ;)

Comment: Yes, I had run into that a while ago.  Quite apart from the fact that it will not work with MariaDB 10 that technique discusses how to attach an asynch slave to a Galera cluster - as a sort of bolt-on capability to Galera's main purpose of doing synchronous master-master synchronization

Comment: Ah, OK – I hadn't read it in-depth. Working with Oracle databases, I just had in mind that sync to a standby database can be setup to be immediate or deferred; and knowing about the existence of MySQL/MariaDB clustering, I thought there should be something similar. Well, I better shut-up then – I never clustered the MySQL databases I use, so I'm not having any "real-life experiences" in this field. Good luck, though! Am curious for the answers, as for a "deferred sync" I currently had a good use-case as well ;)

Comment: I currently do this via a PHP script run off a CRON job on a "synchronization" server.  It polls the various MariaDB servers, picks DB changes and parcels them off to the other servers. On each of those servers, where I use PDO, I have written up a dbExec($sql,$omit,$priority) function which squirrels unomitted SQL statements to a database table. Priority is an internal thing - I prioritize sync ops for high priority users. This works - perfectly but is clearly a hackish solution by someone who does not really understand what he is doing (me :-/)